# Finding nearest point of route using ST_DWITHIN

Tags: postgis, distance, proximity, st-dwithin

I'm new to PostGIS and distance comparisons and am having some problems with my current project. I have a an array of geopoints (long lat) which correspond to a route. And I need to find the nearest point of that route compared to my current position (long lat). I made a query using `ST_ClosestPoint()` but this is too slow due to the performance and gives me a point on the route and not specifically one of the geo array that I can use to link to other data.

```sql
SELECT
    ST_X (ST_ClosestPoint(line,pt)) AS latitude, 
    ST_Y (ST_ClosestPoint(line,pt)) AS longitude 
FROM (
    SELECT
        'POINT({latitude} {longitude})'::geometry AS pt,
        'LINESTRING ({streetLineString})'::geometry As line
    ) AS foo;
```

I have read that using `ST_DWITHIN()` should be higher performance due to index usage, but I do not understand how to change my current query to implement this.

NOTE: streetLineString is a cast due to the original table being an array of objects which contain an array of geopoint objects. It is transformed with a for each loop:

```
streetLineString += geopoint.Latitude + " " + geopoint.Longitude + ", "
```

Comment: if you really want a point of your raw data array to be the closest. Try cast your data in multipoints instead of linestring. only use ST_closesestPoint one and ask ST_X and ST_y of the result (here you are doing twice the heavy process of looking for the closestpoint). Not sure St_Dwithin will do much better ...

Comment: On a side note, coordinates should be longitude first, then latitude. Yours are swapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will propose this query :

```
with raw_data_roads as
( select ST_Collect("inputstreetpoints") as line),
res as (
    select ST_ClosestPoint(raw_data_roads.line,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point({latitude}, {longitude}), 4326)) as geom
    from raw_data_roads
)
select ST_X(res.geom) , ST_Y(res.geom) from res
```

You have two things better with this :

- I use a MultiPoint format for your point array dataset, so the result will be one  of your original point and not some point along the road the dataset represent
- Only use St_ClosestPoint once, because if you use it twice, then you pay the price twice

I don't know if St_Dwithin will help you a lot in your case

Comment: On a side note, coordinates should be longitude first, then latitude. Yours are swapped.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Maximilien jaffrès, the final solution ended up like this:

```
WITH raw_data_roads AS
( SELECT ST_Collect(ARRAY[ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(51.056263076711446,3.7270707882305545), 4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(51.05618577685494,3.4272373015303986), 4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT(51.055975179565884,3.8276880582826224), 4326)]) as line),

res AS (
    SELECT ST_ClosestPoint(raw_data_roads.line,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(51.05484314, 3.73177228), 4326)) AS geom
    FROM raw_data_roads
)
SELECT ST_X(res.geom) , ST_Y(res.geom) FROM res
```